# pdns (powerdns) not returning records anymore after switching db backends

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, postgresql, powerdns

I switched db backends from gmysql to gpgsql and copied the records from the mysql database to the postgresql db. `dig +short www.example.com @my_dns_server_ip` used to return the desired result but it does not anymore.

I upgraded to powerdns 4.1.4 but I still don't get the desired output.

I believe at one point my pdns server useded the gpgsql backend and was able to return the desired output but that stopped working. can anyone help?

Here is my configuration file: https://dpaste.de/hgg9

```
config-dir=/etc/powerdns
gpgsql-dbname=powerdns
gpgsql-host=/run/postgresql
gpgsql-password=pw
gpgsql-user=root
include-dir=/etc/powerdns/pdns.d
launch=gpgsql
local-address=0.0.0.0
security-poll-suffix=
setgid=pdns
setuid=pdns
```

Comment: Does it give any log messages? I believe its log messages are in `/var/log/daemon.log`.

Comment: Ands possibly lncrease the `loglevel=` setting to get more verbose errors

Answer (score 0):

pdns.local.gpgsql.conf had incorrect settings. changed them to the correct ones and server is running and returning records fine now.